# Is there difference in speed between Dictionary.ContainsKey/Value and a foreach loop that checks for a certain key/value

Tags: c#, optimization

Is there difference in speed between `Dictionary.ContainsKey/Value` and a `foreach` loop that checks for a certain key/value?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us?

Comment: Why doesn't someone try it and tell us !  Lots of opinion, no data.

Comment: I tried, did 2 methods, one uses containsKey and one for loop, and used them in a loop of 1000000 iterations(one at the time), the one with the for loop was a little bit faster

Comment: But that's probably also because there is time needed to access the dictionary, cuz with the for loop I was iterating through a collection and with the containskey I created a dictionary of <int, string> for a specific property of a class of mine

Comment: The ContainsKey is faster, it's not an opinion.
You should try with a dictionary containing more than 10 items. With a really small set of items, a simple comparaison might be faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) is faster :

> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

[ContainsValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah.aspx) is like a foreach loop.

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, the average execution time is proportional to Count. That is, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

`ContainsKey` is nearly O(1). As for `ContainsValue`, I can't tell for sure, but I think there won't be much difference to a loop.